# Vectorization of column search by dynamic value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I am starting to learn Pandas. And which day I can not solve the fastest way to calculate. How to get for each row the value of a column by a unique name, composed of column 'a', 'b' values?

Below is an example of the initial data.

| index | a | b | a1_b1_name | a1_b1_foo_bar | a2_b1_name | a2_b1_foo_bar | a1_b2_name | a1_b2_foo_bar | a2_b2_name | a2_b2_foo_bar | a1_b3_name | a1_b3_foo_bar | a2_b3_name | a2_b3_foo_bar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value7 | value8 | value9 | value10 | value11 | value12 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | value13 | value14 | value15 | value16 | value17 | value18 | value19 | value20 | value21 | value22 | value23 | value24 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | value25 | value26 | value27 | value28 | value29 | value30 | value31 | value32 | value33 | value34 | value35 | value36 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | value37 | value38 | value39 | value40 | value41 | value42 | value43 | value44 | value45 | value46 | value47 | value48 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | value49 | value50 | value51 | value52 | value53 | value54 | value55 | value56 | value57 | value58 | value59 | value60 |

The number of columns with the values "a _b _name " is planned to be much larger, about 40. The number of rows will be in the tens of thousands.

I need to create a new column 'name' based on the data of the table as quickly as possible and preferably without loops, using the power of pandas vectorization.

Like this one:

| index | name | foo_bar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | value5 | value6 |
| 1 | value15 | value16 |
| 2 | value31 | value32 |
| 3 | value37 | value38 |
| 4 | value59 | value60 |

I was only able to do this by looping through the columns. But it takes more time than I'd like:

```
for col in df.columns:
     df['name'] = np.where(col == 'a' + (df['a'].astype('Int16').astype(str)) + '_b' + (df['b'].astype('Int16').astype(str)) + '_name', df[col].values, df['name'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### original question

Cf. [first version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76556232/1)

This is a variant on an [indexing lookup](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup), you first need to pre-process your input columns a/b to match the column names:

```
target = 'a'+df['a'].astype(str)+'_b'+df['b'].astype(str)+'_name'

idx, cols = pd.factorize(target)

out = pd.DataFrame({'index': df['index'],
                    'values': df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()
                              [np.arange(len(df)), idx],
                    })

# or, for a new column in the original DataFrame
# df['new'] = df.reindex(cols, axis=1).to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), idx]
```

Output:

```
   index   values
0      0   value3
1      1   value8
2      2  value16
3      3  value19
4      4  value30
```

Intermediate `target`:

```
0    a1_b2_name
1    a2_b1_name
2    a2_b2_name
3    a1_b1_name
4    a2_b3_name
dtype: object
```

##### multiple columns:

One option is to reshape and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
target = 'a'+df['a'].astype(str)+'_b'+df['b'].astype(str)

tmp = df.drop(columns=['index', 'a', 'b'])
tmp.columns = tmp.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)

out = (df
   .reset_index()
   .merge(tmp.stack(level=0), left_on=['index', target], right_index=True)
   .set_index('index')[['name', 'foo']]
)
```

Output:

```
          name      foo
index                  
0       value5   value6
1      value15  value16
2      value31  value32
3      value37  value38
4      value59  value60
```

Comment: What if there are multiple column types? And what to do if there are several types of columns, like: a1_b1_name, a1_b1_foo, a1_b1_bar. Where you also need to get the values for the same values 'a', 'b'?

Comment: @sergeyvyazov it depends on the exact scenario, but likely you'd need to reshape first. Maybe provide an example as edit?

Comment: I've added missing data in the question for clarification

Comment: Writes 'name 'tmp' is not defined'

Comment: Ooops forgot to copy that ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! I'll try to implement everything now

Comment: The fact is that names after ' a1_b1_' can also have even several ' _' (for example: a1_b3_name_foo_bar ). But it is known for sure that all column names have the same indexing by the second and fifth characters. Eg: a1_b1_name_foo, a1_b1_foo_name, a1_b1_bar_foo, a1_b1_name_foo_bar_name_bar_foo

Comment: I corrected the original data of the tables

Comment: Please tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: You can try to replace `tmp.columns = tmp.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)` by `tmp.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(tmp.columns.str.extract('(a[^_]+_b[^_]+)_(.*)'))`. Please don't keep changing the format ;)

Comment: Works! Thank you! And how to leave two columns 'a', 'b' in the final table?

Comment: Instead of slicing `[['name', 'foo']]`, use `[['a', 'b', 'name', 'foo']]`

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything works as it should